# $inc only if value is greater than 0 (Node.js mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I have following updating query

```
this.dbService.getCollection(DBCollections.CHANNEL)
  .updateMany(
    {
      'members.skipRounds': { $exists: true },
      _id: channelId,
    },
    { $inc: { 'members.$[].skipRounds': -1 } },
  ).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

How can I make the value of skipRounds decrement by -1 ONLY if the current value is greater than 0?

This is what my channels collection look like

```
Channels [
{
  _id:1
  users:[
  {
    _id:1
    skipRounds:1
  },
  {
    _id:2
    skipRounds:3
  },       
  ]
},
{
  _id:2
  users:[
  {
    _id:1
    skipRounds:3
  },
  {
    _id:2
    skipRounds:5
  },       
  ]
},   
]
```

Comment: add $gt as 'members.skipRounds': { $exists: true,$gt:0} in query

Comment: @sushantmehta It still decrements when the value of skipRounds is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this one it may help you.

```
    this.dbService.getCollection(DBCollections.CHANNEL).updateMany(
    {
      'users.skipRounds': { $exists: true },
    },
    { $inc: { 'users.$[element].skipRounds': -1 } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "element.skipRounds": { $gt: 0 } } ]}
).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Hm. It doesn't seem to work. I've added my collection structure to my question so you can see it.

Comment: @BorisGrunwald as per your input. i have made some changed please check updated code.